# How to write query for deleting records in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new in android. I made an app in which two buttons are there one is start_tracking and it will ask for how many hours you want to track. and other button is show_history in which it will show whatever u tracked. But I stuck in one place in which,if I want to track again and after that if I want to see history again it will delete the previous record and show the latest one.

Comment: Do you have some tracking id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MYDATABASE_TABLE -> Table Name**

**Deleting all records**

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

**Delete records with where condition**

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID+"="+id, null); //KEY_ID is column name
sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

**Delete Multiple data**

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE,new String("value1=? and value2=? and value3=?"),new String[]{value1,value2,value3});
sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

**Delete data with execSQL (Plain SQL Query)**

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE value1='"+string1+"' AND value2='"+string2+"' AND value3='"+string3+"' "); //Here you can write as query
sqLiteDatabase.close();
```